# Google authentication when multiple user password is saved

Tags: java, google-authentication

I have done google authentication for my web application. When the user is signed in to google account then only the application will be accessible. Else it will ask the user to Login to their google account. Even after the authentication, on every page load am checking whether the user is still logged in or not. If not, will redirect him to the login page of google. If the user is still logged in, will navigate him to the appropriate page.

Problem: Now if the user has multiple google account. and has saved password in both the accounts, when i try to navigate, it asks me which account to use everytime. How can i avoid this? If one of the required account is logged in i should be able to navigate without having to ask the user to select which account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Google checks whether or not it has a valid login token for a user.  If not, then it prompts you to select a user.  Do you have a logged in user at the point in the end of your question?

Comment: once i login, am able to fetch the logged in user name, and other details. But say i logged in to google with 2 accounts and for both i save password, then the trouble starts. Cant i check whether this account is logged in or not and proceed further?